# NFS directories mapping as nobody:nobody on Solaris 9 box

Tags: solaris, ownership, nas, automount

I've set up a Solaris 9 test box.  Individual user home directories are on a local NAS that is automounted at boot time via /etc/vfstab entry.

Unlike other solaris servers on the LAN, home directories on the test box are listed as having user:group ownership "nobody:nobody" instead of [username]:[primary-group].

Also, when users ssh into the test box, the prompt displays their UID instead of username.

What have I overlooked?

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: You've overlooked at least the site to ask on. StackOveflow is dedicated to practical *programming* questions.

Comment: My apologies.  I was under the impression that programmers knew more about a given OS than the average admin these days.